# React: Unterminated JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am relatively new to react. I was trying to split my code in App.js components. Now, I am getting an error.

```
  ./src/containers/App.js
Syntax error: Unterminated JSX contents (64:12)

  62 |           Toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler} />
  63 |           {person}
> 64 |       </div>
     |             ^
  65 |      )
  66 |    }
  67 | }
```

Here is my cockpit.js file (**inside src/components/cockpit/cockpit.js**)

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './cockpit.css';

const Ccockpit = (props) => {
  const assignedClasses = [];
  let btnClass = ''
  btnClass = cockpit.red;

  if (cocPersonState) {
      btnClass = cockpit.red;
  }

  if (props.cocperson.length <= 2) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.red)
  }
  if (props.cocperson.length <= 1) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.bold)
  }
  return(
    <div className={classes.cockpit}>
      <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
      <p className={assignedClasses.join(' ')}>hey </p>
      <button className={btnClass}
      onClick={props.Toggler}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Ccockpit;
```

And this is what I am doing in **App.js file (src/containers/app.js)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './App.css';
import Cperson from '../components/person/person.js';
import Ccockpit from '../components/cockpit/cockpit.js';

class App extends Component {
(some code here) 

render() {
(some code here) 
return (
      <div className={classes.App}>
      <Ccockpit>
          cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
          cocperson = {this.state.person}
          Toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler} />
          {person}

      </div>
     )
   }
}
export default App;
```

Any Idea what could be wrong here? and fixes for the same?

Comment: You're missing a closing tag for that div, should be `<div className={classes.App}>`

Comment: @Jayce444 fixed it but still getting the same error

Comment: @Jayce444 okay, Now it throws an error Unterminated JSX contents

Comment: The exact same error on the exact same line? Also, in your `cockpit.js`, render function, the containing div has a misspelled prop, it should be "className". You're missing the c.

Comment: Yeah fixed that as well. Nope, few lines below in App.js 
https://imgur.com/a/8DCxq

Comment: `Toggler` is another component?

Comment: It's because your JSX syntax is wrong. You can either have `<Tag {props}>content</Tag>` or `<Tag {props}/>`. But you have an opening tag (`<Ccockpit>`) but you don't close it with `</Ccockpit>`. Change `<Ccockpit>` to `<Ccockpit`

Comment: Where is {person} defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Ccockpit
          cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
          cocperson = {this.state.person}
          Toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler} />
```