# React: Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my code to toggle a person handler, Before it was working but since I split into components, It seem to have broken.

Toggle happens on button click (see inside return statement <

```
button className={btnClass}
      onClick={props.toggler}>Button</button>
```

Here is my entire cockpit.js file (**inside src/components/cockpit/cockpit.js**).

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './cockpit.css';

const Ccockpit = (props) => {
  const assignedClasses = [];
  let btnClass = ''
  if (props.cocPersonState) {
      btnClass = classes.red;
      console.log(".......")
  }

  if (props.cocperson <= 2) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.red)
  }
  if (props.cocperson <= 1) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.bold)
  }
  return(
    <div className={classes.cockpit}>
      <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
      <p className={assignedClasses.join(' ')}>hey </p>
      <button className={btnClass}
      onClick={props.toggler}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Ccockpit;
```

and inside App.js

```
 return (
      <div className={classes.App}>
      <Ccockpit>
          cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
          cocperson = {this.state.person.length}
          toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler}
        </Ccockpit>
            {person}
      </div>
     )
   }
}
```

and this is my **`togglerpersonHandler`** code.

```
togglerPersonHandler = () => {
  const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
  this.setState({
    showPerson: !doesShow
  });
}
```

I can't see to figure out that why it won't toggle and console.log/change color to red (It isn't changing the state). Can someone please review and figure out the mistake?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you asked a nearly identical question regarding your JSX already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848598/react-unterminated-jsx

Comment: They both are very different Question Dan. That problem is fixed, this one is a new error

Comment: the solution to this question was presented to you in the comments of your previous question.

Comment: Yes, I implemented them and that fixed that issue. Now, this is a different issue Dan. (This does not throw any error rather does not perform task it is supposed to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSX still isn't right. Please review the JSX syntax with regards to giving it props/children.

You have this:

```
<Ccockpit>
    cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
    cocperson = {this.state.person.length}
    toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler}
</Ccockpit>
```

But those values aren't children, they're properties. So they need to be in the opening tag, like this:

```
<Ccockpit
    cocPersonState = {this.state.showPerson}
    cocperson = {this.state.person.length}
    toggler = {this.togglerPersonHandler}/>
```

Revisit some React tutorials to see how JSX should be structured and how it works.